# Magento 2 : Custom Module Only Working One Time

Tags: magento2, module, command-line

I made a custom module to add an extra field into a Magento 2 table. It worked fine when I run

```
        php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

The extra field is added into table. I deleted field, and tried to run module with same command again, but extra field is not added.

I didn't get any error when I ran same command again. But at the end, it show a green line with text "**Please re-run Magento compile command**". I'm not sure if this is the reason?

or did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to re-run the custom extension and need to create a field again.

Remove extension entry from "setup_module" table of database.

Then run above command.